# SQl - An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Getting this error with the following query in SQL Server 2014.

```
SELECT 
      [Case]
      ,[Course]
      ,[Device]
      ,[IntegerValue]     
      ,[Question]
      ,IFL.[QuestionSimplified]
      ,[Revision]
      ,[Script]    
      ,[TextValue]
      ,[Timestamp]
      ,[Type]
      ,[Variable]     
      ,[Wave]
  FROM [dbo].[CosmosData] CD
  Left Outer join [dbo].[ImportedFacilityList] IFL on CD.[Variable] = IFL.[Variablename]
  where 
CD.[Script] = 'CARD-F' and 

(select  * from [dbo].[CosmosData] where Variable = 'SURVEY_TYPE' and IntegerValue = '2')
```

When I run the above query I am getting the beloiw error,

Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

Any help please?

Comment: what criteria are you applying to test against your select in where clause?

Comment: @jimmy8ball I wanted to display records from the database 'CosmosData' where column Variable = 'SURVEY_TYPE' and column IntegerValue = '2'

Comment: and what data item are you testing for the presence of in cosmos data?

Comment: a better question, what combination of fields in this table makes a unique record?

Comment: @jimmy8ball Thanks, I managed to get the answer

Comment: thanks can you mark the question as answered and satisfied please

Answer (score 4):

You have this in the `where` clause:

```
and (select  * from [dbo].[CosmosData] where Variable = 'SURVEY_TYPE' and IntegerValue = '2')
```

SQL needs a *boolean* expression.  This is usually formed by using `=` or a similar comparison operator.  In your case, I think you just exant `exists`:

```
exists (select  * from [dbo].[CosmosData] where Variable = 'SURVEY_TYPE' and IntegerValue = 2)
```

That said, you might want a correlation clause as well.

Note:  I removed the single quotes from the integer value.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Answer (score 0):

based on the assumption that you are using case as a key in this table, you can use the follwing to return all rows from cosmos data where your conditions are applied and the select in your where clause has a match using the criteria within it.

```
 SELECT 
  [Case]
  ,[Course]
  ,[Device]
  ,[IntegerValue]     
  ,[Question]
  ,IFL.[QuestionSimplified]
  ,[Revision]
  ,[Script]    
  ,[TextValue]
  ,[Timestamp]
  ,[Type]
  ,[Variable]     
  ,[Wave]
FROM [dbo].[CosmosData] CD
Left Outer join [dbo].[ImportedFacilityList] IFL on CD.[Variable] = IFL.  [Variablename]
where CD.[Script] = 'CARD-F' 
and Case
 IN
 (select  Case from [dbo].[CosmosData] where Variable = 'SURVEY_TYPE' and     IntegerValue = '2')
```

Hope that helps any